# webpack issue when trying to run development environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

**Before you read this sorry for splitting my code into separate documents, it wat too long for Stackoverflow editor.**

I get this error when i run my development environment:

Configuration file found but no entry configured.

Use --help to display the CLI options.

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
let config;

if (/development/.test(process.env.NODE_ENV.indexOf('development'))) {
    config = require('./config/webpack.dev')({env: 'development'});
}
else if (/production|staging/.test(process.env.NODE_ENV)) {
    config = require('./config/webpack.prod')({env: 'production'});
}

module.export = config;
```

**This is my config/webpack.dev.js:**

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oudL50sL84FQDGB7vmuYcr2yVll44UlLr5DPPuZ2-kk/edit?usp=sharing

**This is my webpack.common.js:**

some code that i reuse for production and development environment

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JMQPxMbLGsOGddohkZyhbvYE1CSXWImxJll3JVQ4rQA/edit?usp=sharing

**This is my package.json:**

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uk5yXCjMbBCnhGqKzrQRAEUDewwPWd_UeW3Zld4oV7w/edit?usp=sharing

**I print my screen to show the console.log i did for the config inside my webpack.config file when i run the npm run dev:**

http://up416.siz.co.il/up3/eqho2ydz2j2t.png

**This is my app structure:**

http://up416.siz.co.il/up2/y2tni0ny11mt.png

Answer (score 0):

I think Webpacks' error makes sense. It finds the configuration file, **webpack.config.js**, but there's no 'entry' property on the value that's exported.

Firstly, `module.export` should be `module.exports`. In your example, nothing will be exported, hence there being no entry property.

Once that's fixed, I think there's another issue; looks like the below condition is wrong:

```
/development/.test(process.env.NODE_ENV.indexOf('development'))
```

Should it be this instead?

```
/development/.test(process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

Since no conditions evaluate to `true`, `config` will be exported as `undefined`, which will probably give you the same error.

Comment: Acctually you are right this is very nooby of me, but still after this fix i'm getting the same issue,
I print my screen to show the console.log i did for the config inside my webpack.config file when i run the npm run dev:
http://up416.siz.co.il/up3/eqho2ydz2j2t.png

This is my app structure:
http://up416.siz.co.il/up2/y2tni0ny11mt.png

Comment: I think you need module.exports instead of module.export - I've updated my answer :)

Comment: Wow i'm very very sorry for this stupid mistake, thanks it worked, just a typo...